# Unknown error while configuring Oracle 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: database, ubuntu, oracle11g, configuration

I have installed Oracle 11g on Ubuntu as per this link: [Oracle 11g installation steps on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I reached to the step where it says to configure Oracle. I am able to execute the command successfully. First it asks to enter HTTP Port, which I entered successfully. Then it asks to enter database listener port, which I entered successfully. Then I entered the password successfully for database account. And finally I said yes for Oracle to be started on boot.

It showed be an error `Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details`. Here I am stuck. I don't really know what error could be. I am sharing the steps and message here. Here is the command:

```
rakshit@user:/home/rakshitbhatt/Disk1$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Here is the internal message:

### Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration

This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express 
Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should 
be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that 
will be used for database accounts.  Press  to accept the defaults. 
Ctrl-C will abort.

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:8080

Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:1521

Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of 
different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after 
initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details

Could you help me with it? I am not a technical guy. Thanks!

Comment: Hi There! Just to share with you all that the issue has been resolved. This issue occurs as there is no sufficient swap memory. I found a link that helps with it [http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.in/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html]. Thank you for your time and efforts.